# Install mxnet 0.12.1 on AWS cuda9 deep learning AMI

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, installation, deep-learning, mxnet

AWS deep learning AMIs come with mxnet 0.12.0 RC. Apparently this version has a bug that sets random initialization weights to 0. How to I remove the preinstalled mxnet and upgrade?

Logged in via SHH as ec2-user, I tried

```
cd src
sudo rm -rf mxnet
git clone --recursive github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet.git mxnet
```

but the R-package build fails. Do I have to make/compile the program prior to R-package? Because that also fails. This package installation only works with a nightmare of inconsistent LD library configurations.

Comment: Can you provide more details? 
Which DL AMI are you using? If you built MXNet again, what flags did you use? Do you want to use the R package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to compile the MXNet program before building R package. The detailed installation guide is here: http://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/install/index.html

Comment: Didn't have any issues with the compile and build this time, but the make rpkg command didn't actually create anything (no tar.gz for R to install). The command execute without errors, but produced no file.

Comment: The real tip here is to use ubuntu, then the installation instructions work no problem. AWS linux install is a mess.